# Error:- HTTP ERROR 408 on AWS

Tags: iis-8, amazon-elb

Error: - This page isn’t working if the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 408

Backed: 
TWO IIS Web-server and  AWS loadbalancer

We have deployed the same site on IIS webserver both the servers are placed behind the AWS classic load balancer.

We have installed the SSL using letsencrpyt one of the IIS server and exported the SSL and then installed the same on the 2nd IIS web server. Locally the site is working and can see that the website is fully secure.

Locally the site is working and can see that the website is fully secure.

Further, we pulled the Private Key: * and Certificate body: * data and installed the same SSL on AWS load balancer But when we try to server the same site through the load balancer it’s not working and we are getting the error: - Error: - This page isn’t working if the problem continues, contact the site owner. HTTP ERROR 408

No logs are being captured in the IIS logs.

Please assist.

Warm Regards,

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Getting the same issue. I wonder if anyone else encountered this problem.